# Hwo to compare these two arrays the way they are built using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Array 1 `values` is built by getting the values from the ranges mapped through a range list and Arra2 is a row obtained from another range. I see that these arrays' structures are not similar and it's not possible to compare them the way they are, but what can I change in the code so that the comparison works?

These is how the data look:
[image]

This is the code I'm getting humiliated by:

```
function saveEditedItem() {
  const ssCadProd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetCadProd = ssCadProd.getSheetByName('Cadastro de Produto');

  const ref = sheetCadProd.getRange('B5').getValue();
  const variac = sheetCadProd.getRange('K5').getValue();

  //MAPS DATA RANGES
  const dataRng = [
    "B5", "D5", "G5", "I5", "K5",
  ];
  const rngList = sheetCadProd.getRangeList(dataRng).getRanges();

  //THROW MAPPED DATA INTO AN ARRAY
  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rngList.length; i++) {
    values = [].concat(values, rngList[i].getValue());
  }
  Logger.log('Values: ' + values)
  Logger.log('Values Length: ' + values.length)
  //GETS THE ITEM WITH THE SAME REF AND VARIAC
  const produtosDB = sheetCadProd.getRange(10, 1, 3, 5).getValues();
  let prodSelecDB = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < produtosDB.length; a++) {
    if (produtosDB[a][0] == ref && produtosDB[a][4] == variac) {
      prodSelecDB.push(produtosDB[a])
    }
  }
  Logger.log('prodSelecDB: ' + prodSelecDB)
  Logger.log('prodSelecDB Length: ' + prodSelecDB.length)

  Logger.log('Stringified Values: ' + JSON.stringify(values))
  Logger.log('Stringified ProdSelecDB: ' + JSON.stringify(prodSelecDB))

  //COMPARES Values' DATA WITH ProdSelecDB's
  var duplicate = false;
    for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < prodSelecDB.length; j++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(values[x]) == JSON.stringify(prodSelecDB[j])) {
          duplicate = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  Logger.log('Are they the same? ' + duplicate)
}
```

These are the logs:
[image]

Here's the link to the file, in case you feel like jumping in:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1N6rHP7qIheDDUkcQiNfEZ4rmjrguBHYoyWuTuWwKw/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate your time, as usual!

Comment: For single cell ranges use getValue instead of getValues as the last will return a Array of Arrays of values.

Comment: Hi, @Rubén! I'm still getting the same result, which is ```false``` when they're both the same (apparently).

Comment: Try this `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values[x]))` and `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(prodSelecDB[j])` and see what you get.  I'll bet you they are different.

Comment: You're right, @TheWizEd! How do I make them common, structure-wise? Just updated the log outputs above. Thank you!

Comment: values is an array of values, prodSelectDB is an array of rows.  values[0] = 10001, selectProdDB[0] = [10001, 78911521212,....]

Comment: Do you see one value has `[` and second value has `[[` - it's a difference, that's why it returns false when you compare them.

Comment: Hi, @Kos. I see that. How can I make them have the same structure? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense `if (JSON.stringify(values[x]) == JSON.stringify(prodSelecDB[j])) {
          duplicate = true;
          break;` you are comparing a single value to a row and it makes even less sense to use JSON. stringify as well.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you wish to compare them?

Comment: @Cooper, where can I tweak it so they can be compared? Do I need to flatten ```prodSelecDB``` or do something like that prior to comparison? Thanks.

Comment: compared in what way?

Comment: I get ```values``` and I compare it with ```prodSelecDB```. If they differ in any of the words in them, ```duplicate``` is to be ```false```. So I'll replace the row in ```prodSelecDB``` with the new one, updated. @Cooper.

Comment: But you want to be able to compare them row by row right?

Comment: Yes, @Cooper. Thanks.

Comment: Is your fourth value in the top table actually in a merge range?

Comment: ...the one containing 7891... , yes, @Cooper. But only G5 cell is mapped in the range list. I guess it makes discards the fact that its merged, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241369/discussion-between-cooper-and-santosonit).

Comment: `for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {` is wrong because x has only 1 entry [10001, 78911521212,...].  Try this `if (JSON.stringify(values) == JSON.stringify(prodSelecDB[j])) {` just to show that the Array values is equal to the first row of Array prodSelecDB.

Comment: Sorry didn't write that last comment correctly.  values is an array, prodSelecDB is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could look for full row matches this way

```
function compare() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const v0s = sh0.getRange(1,1,1,sh0.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().map(r => [r[1],r[3],r[6],r[8],r[10]].join(""));
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const v1s = sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow() - 1,sh1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let n = 0;
  v1s.forEach((r,i) => {
    let j = r.join("");
    let idx = v0s.indexOf(j);
    if(~idx) {
      //there is a match and for this example it occurs on row idx + 1
      n++;
    }
  })
  Logger.log('matches: %s',n)
} 


Execution log
2:02:36 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:02:37 PM  Info    matches: 1.0
2:02:37 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Sheet0:

[image]

Sheet1:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I care about reusability and you can build a custom function with the script I made. I didn't know where you're gonna output that code, but I made a `console.log()` however you can modify it as you need it

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

function saveEditedItem() {
  const array1 = getArray1()
  const array2= getArray2('A11:E11')
  console.log(compareArr(array1, array2))
  return compareArr(array1, array2)
}

function compareArr(arr1, arr2) {
  const string1 = JSON.stringify(arr1)
  const string2 = JSON.stringify(arr2)

  if(string1 === string2){
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function getArray1() {
  const listRange = ['B5', 'D5', 'G5', 'I5', 'K5']
  const rngList = ss.getRangeList(listRange).getRanges()
  return extractArray(rngList)
}

function getArray2(range){
  const array = ss.getRange(range).getValues()
  return array[0]
}

function extractArray(rngList) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rngList.length; i++) {
    array = [].concat(array, rngList[i].getValue());
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, David.